# Zip keys of a Map<string,List<Double>> with a new List as old List was transformed

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I express the following snippet as a lambda?

```
int i = 0;
for (String key : latLng.keySet()) {
    map.put(key, latLngMercator.get(i++));
}
```

where `latLng` is a `Map<String, List<Double>>` and `latLngMercator` is a `List<List<Double>>`.

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Is `latLng` ordered? Otherwise you're mapping indexes to arbitrary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `latLngMercator` values would be assigned to random `latLng` keys if the `Map` implementation that `latLng` uses does not maintain insertion order (like a `HashMap`). Depending on the intended functionality, a `LinkedHashMap` or another `Map` implementation that maintains insertion order might be the way to go.

This should work:

```java
Iterator<List<Double>> iterator = latLngMercator.iterator();
latLng.forEach((key, value) -> map.put(key, iterator.next()));
```